# is raspberry pi 5 suitable for blender 3d rendering through command line?

Tags: pi-5

I was wondering if the raspberry pi 5 (8gb version) is suitable for blender 3d rendering through command line? or shloud i chose something like the orange pi or the rock pi ?

Comment: you can definitely try ... update your question with the result